# Rails url helpers not available in name spaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a name spaced controller that is from a gem I am creating, and it seems that none of the `*_path` or `*_url` helpers that come from the routes are available for any of the other models when trying to load one of the actions.  I can't seem to figure out why they are not available in just this controller.

Controller

```
class Surveyor::AttemptsController < ApplicationController
 load_and_authorize_resource

 before_filter :load_active_survey

 def new
  @participant = current_user

  unless @survey.nil?
   @attempt = @survey.attempts.new
   @attempt.answers.build
  end
 end

 def create
  @attempt = @survey.attempts.new(params[:survey_attempt])
  @attempt.participant = current_user

  if @attempt.valid? && @attempt.save
    redirect_to view_context.new_attempt, alert: I18n.t("attempts_controller.#{action_name}")
   else
    render :action => :new
   end
  end

  private

  def load_active_survey
   @survey =  Surveyor::Survey.active.first
  end
end
```

Routes

```
...
namespace :surveyor do
  resources :attempts, :only => [:new, :create]
end
...
```

Every other route is fine but these.  I get the error:

```
undefined method `team_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000010f330bc0>:0x00000107500840>
```

Team is another model and I have a partial that calls this, this just happens to be the first call to *_path, if I change this it just keeps failing further down the render. Here is the html:

```
<li><a href="<%= team_path(current_user.team) %>">My Team</a></li>
```

current_user is indeed defined and available

Any ideas?  I've given a good search but everything is related to people not defining @variable in their controller method for a page with a form, which is not the case for me.

EDIT (SOLUTION):

Turns out for some reason when I add `helper Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` into my controller everything works fine.  This seems to be more a bug in rails than anything, as i shouldn't have to do that, but oh well.

Comment: Do `rake routes | grep team`.  This will show you all the paths relating to `team`.  Does that path exist?

Comment: Yeah all the routes exist, just the helpers seem unavailable in only this controller, all other controllers work fine

Comment: I can't see you using a path helper in the controller, where you say the problem is. Have you posted a workaround, maybe using helpers?

Comment: I am not using it in the controller, but rather in a view.  Specifically team_path is being called in application.html.erb and in my route of /surveyor/attempt/new, this team_path is not available, but in all other controller actions in the app it is fine

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
app.team_path
```

to access the path helper where you wouldn't normally (like in the console).

It is puzzling that just namespacing the controller would do this though. I'll try to recreate at some point.

Comment: Now i get undefined local variable or method `app' for #<#<Class:0x0000010bfa8780>:0x0000010149f7f8>

Comment: also `2.1.0 :004 > app.surveyor_attempts_path` returns the correct url in the console, but just not this one controller actions view

Comment: Where is your controller located in your gem's directory structure?

Comment: its app/controllers/surveyor/attempts_controller.rb.  Also i found a solution and edit my question above

Comment: Glad you found a workaround. Are you doing this as an engine or just a regular gem?